# Symfony2 - Twig render controller. Constraints form display

Tags: php, symfony

I need to render a controller in a template (principal.html.twig) with @Route and @Template annotations in order to create a form:

`{{ render(controller('PprsBundle:Default:SupuestoConfig'), {'strategy': 'inline'}) }`

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/configsup", name="configsup")
 * @Template("PprsBundle:Default:SupuestoConfig.html.twig")
 */
public function SupuestoConfigAction()
{
    ...

     ->add('number', 'text', array(
                    'constraints' => new Length(array(
                            'min' => 1,
                            'max' => 2,
                         )), 

    ....
}
```

routing.yml:

`configsup:
    resource: "@PprsBundle/Controller"
    type: annotation`

SupuestoConfig.html.twig:

```
<form id="configurador" action="{{ path('configsup') }}" method="POST">
    <p class="titulo_configurador">Elija supuesto penal:</p>
        {{ form_row(form.tipo) }}
    {{ form_row(form.numero, { 'label' : ' ', 'attr' : { 'class' : 'rec3' }}) }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input id= "btTipoSupuesto" type="submit" value="Cargar" class="inputbt"/>
</form>
```

I'm having an unexpected behaviour when the constraint is activated (when I introduce a 4 digits number in "number" field) because it only renders the view **SupuestoConfig.html.twig** showing the constraint error (route /configsup) instead of the whole page (principal.html.twig). How can i make it work?

Comment: Is there another solution? I've create two different embedded forms in the same view (principal.html.twig) and I don't think I should add all code in the same controller to avoid that behaviour because of the constraint error display in the form view.

Comment: From your `SupuestoConfigAction` you can forward the action to the "principal" action if the form is invalid so it renders the whole page not only the form.

Comment: Thanks, It makes sense! I'm trying to redirect the page in case of invalid form, but doing this way I am not able to transfer validation form error to main page :(

Comment: That's why you should have a look at forwarding a controller instead of redirecting the user.

Comment: **$this->forward('PprsBundle:Default:principal',                                 array('numero_supuesto' => $sesion->get('numero_supuesto'),
       ));**  works the same way like redirect(). It doesn't show form constraint errors.

Comment: And that´s because principalAction() renders principal.html.twig and inside it calls a new SupuestoConfigAction() which generates another new form.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the form to the `SupuestoConfigAction` which renders only the form. You should send your form to the action where you render the form originally (where you use `{{ render(controller('PprsBundle:Default:SupuestoConfig'), {'strategy': 'inline'}) }`. Handle the form submission in that action and display the result.

So it's not a strange behaviour. It behaves exactly as you tell your program to.